# Get Selected row of dynamically created table on click of a button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the selected row of the table on click event of a button. The table is dynamically created, i have seen many sample code for this and tried but not any for dynamic created table.

Here is my code:

```
$('#custorder1').on('click', 'tr', function()   
{
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected'); 
    });
    $('.OK').on('click', function(e)
{
        alert($("#custorder1 tr.selected td:first").html());        

 };
```

// Below is the skeleton of table

```
<table class="CSSTableGenerator" id="custorder1" >
               <thead>
                    <tr id="head1">
                        <th>
                            Item No
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Alias
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Brand
                        </th>
                     </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>
                   </tbody>
                </table>
            <input type="button" name="OK" class="OK" value="OK"/>
```

// The basic problem is : function is not called neither on click of tr element nor on click of ok button.

Help Please...

//This is the code for dynamically creation of table

```
function setItemForSale(itemForSale, type,xml)
{

        var itemForSaleTable = document.getElementById("custorder1");
        var itemForSaleTableHead = document.getElementById("head1");
        var itemForSaleTableBody = document.createElement("tbody");

        itemForSaleTableBody.appendChild(itemForSaleTableHead);

        for(var i=0; i< itemForSale.length; i++)
        {
            var row = document.createElement("tr");

                var obj             = itemForSale[i];
                var vitemno         = obj["itemNo"];
                var vname           = obj["name"];
                var valias          = obj["alias"];
                var vbrand          = obj["brand"];

                var cell       = document.createElement("td");
                var cellText   = document.createTextNode(vitemno);
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);

                cell       = document.createElement("td");              
                cellText   = document.createTextNode(vname);
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);

                cell       = document.createElement("td");              
                cellText   = document.createTextNode(valias);
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);

                cell       = document.createElement("td");              
                cellText   = document.createTextNode(vbrand);
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);

                itemForSaleTableBody.appendChild(row);
}
itemForSaleTable.appendChild(itemForSaleTableBody);
itemForSaleTable.setAttribute("border", "2");       
}
```

// here is the Css

```
.selected {
    color: brown;
    background-color: #33afff;
}
```

Comment: How exactly is the table created dynamically?

Comment: You cant click on a table...

Comment: ok i am posting code for creation of table see updated question

Comment: @RishiPandey posted updated anwser. Works now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think now i can answer my own question.
With this code u can select any row in dynamically created table and after select click on button to add that row to another table dynamic created table.

Here is the code for appending table:

```
var firstAmount=0;
function Buy()
{
    for(var i=0;i< data.length;i++) 
    {
        var obj = data[i];

        var vitemNo         = obj["itemNo"];
        var vpkg            = obj["pkg"];
        firstAmount         = obj["regPrice"];

        if(zitemNo == vitemNo && z1Pkg == vpkg)
        {
 // main code for appending creating tr and td and assigning it to variable     
            var Markup = "<tr><td>"+0+"</td><td>"+vmobileNo+"</td><td>"+ vitemNo + "</td><td>"+vpkg+"</td><td>"+firstAmount+"</td><td contenteditable='true'>"+1+"</td></tr>";

       // below code appends it to table
            $("#table2ID tr:last").after(Markup);
        }       
    }
}
```

// function of creating dynamic table:

```
function setItemForSale(data, type,xml)
{   
        var itemForSaleTable = document.getElementById("table1ID");
        var itemForSaleTableHead = document.getElementById("head1");
        var itemForSaleTableBody = document.createElement("tbody");

        itemForSaleTableBody.appendChild(itemForSaleTableHead);

        $('#table1IDtr').has('td').remove();            // Code for clearing table body

        for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++)
        {
            var row = document.createElement("tr");
            row.ondblclick = function()
            {
                //tableRow()
                $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected'); 
                zitemNo = $(this).find('td:first').text();    
                z1Pkg = $(this).find('td:nth-child(8)').text();
            };

                var obj             = data[i];
                var vitemno         = obj["itemNo"];
                var vname           = obj["name"];
                var valias          = obj["alias"];
                var vbrand          = obj["brand"];

                var cell       = document.createElement("td");
                var cellText   = document.createTextNode(vitemno);
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);

                cell       = document.createElement("td");              
                cellText   = document.createTextNode(vname);
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);

                cell       = document.createElement("td");              
                cellText   = document.createTextNode(valias);
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);

                cell       = document.createElement("td");              
                cellText   = document.createTextNode(vbrand);
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);

                itemForSaleTableBody.appendChild(row);
}
itemForSaleTable.appendChild(itemForSaleTableBody);
itemForSaleTable.setAttribute("border", "2");       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

function may not be called if you are not placing it inside `document.ready()` method

```
$( document ).ready( function(){

    $( document ).on('click', '#custorder1 tr', function()   
    {
       $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected'); 
    });
    $('.OK').on('click', function(e)
    {
        alert($("#custorder1 tr.selected td:first").html());        
    };
} );
```

Comment: @ewrwr that won't work if custorder1 is also dynamically created, so the `on` should be started from document

Comment: @RishiPandey please share the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
    var initiate = function(){
        if($('#custorder1') && $('.OK')){
            $('#custorder1 tr').not('#head1').on('click', function(){
                $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected'); 
            });
            $('.OK').on('click', function(e){
                if($('#custorder1 tr.selected').not('#head1')!=null && ($('#custorder1 tr.selected').not('#head1').length == 0))
                    $($("#custorder1 tr").not('#head1')[0]).addClass('selected');
                alert($("#custorder1 tr.selected td:first").html());
            });
        }
    };
```

I have removed the code part which was using interval.
Lets come back to your table generating function. In your function

call the initiate function

```
function setItemForSale(itemForSale, type,xml)
{
    ....
    ....
    itemForSaleTable.setAttribute("border", "2");  
    initiate();
}
```

Comment: I have implemented a demo for you @RishiPandey see here https://jsfiddle.net/ypshyv8f/

Comment: This works if static table is used but as i have already written that i'm trying this for a dynamic table , where this does not work..  u can test it.

Comment: Now this code is having an interval set until it finds the element it runs forever so when the dynamic content is loaded the code is executed as expected @RishiPandey

Comment: also if your more rows are getting added to the table dynamically then just remove the clearInterval(inerval) line from the code. @RishiPandey

Comment: alert is showing undefined ,   means nothing is picked up by tr.selected td:first

Comment: I think clearInterval doesn't create problem but the table should have atleast 1 <tr> element with class selected when table first loads up @RishiPandey

Comment: awwww... still a problem it is showing first column data of all rows ,, i want to pick the first cell data of only selected row

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99339/discussion-between-rajesh-jangid-and-rishipandey).

Comment: I have modified the code considering some important cases which were missing at first like on click of ok at first time it was showing undefined because no row was selected at first. Now it should be working fine. @RishiPandey

Comment: when clicked first row it gets selected and gives right cell but when clicked on any other cell after that not highlighted and saame alert shown. not for current selection..

Comment: I don't know why didn't that worked for you but here i have thought of another workaround to the problem which i have edited see if that helps @RishiPandey